# How to run jboss server in windows?

Tags: windows, jboss, cmd

I am new in jboss and now i am configuring jboss server with windows. I am setting env. variable as:

```
JBOSS_HOME= C:\jboss-4.2.0.GA
Path = C:\jboss-4.2.0.GA\bin
```

and while starting jboss through `run.bat`, it will do nothing just blinking once and disable the prompt.

It will gives me out as

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>   'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look in run.bat you will see that it uses `findstr` command.

```
"%JAVA%" -version 2>&1 | findstr /I hotspot > nul
```

You modified your PATH environment and it cannot find `findstr` which is a native Windows command.

You don't need to modify PATH to use JBOSS. If you do keep old PATH values, like

```
set PATH = C:\jboss-4.2.0.GA\bin;%PATH%
```